# View issues in magnifying UIPickerView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit, uipickerview

I am trying to attach a magnifying view atop the selector of a UIPickerView so that the selected values appear magnified.  I have already found and edited some code that accomplishes this (in UIView custom class):

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(context,1*(self.frame.size.width*0.5),1*(self.frame.size.height*0.5));
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.1, 1.1);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context,-1*(magnifiedPoint.x),-1*(magnifiedPoint.y));
[self.viewToMagnify.layer renderInContext:context];
```

The code copies the current context, alters it and throws it into viewToMagnify.  However it's led me to a slight catch and that is when I actually add the view (in ViewController):

```
if(loop == nil){
    loop = [[MagnifierView alloc] init];
    //[loop setPostition:169 :157 :199 :264];

    loop.viewToMagnify = mainView;
}

[self.view addSubview:loop];

[loop setPosition:myPoint];
```

the end result is a magnified section of my original view.  The problem is that it magnifies itself as well since it is already a part of the view it magnifies.  I've tried adding it to the view's superview but then the magnified view never appears.

Any insight into this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am afraid you are doing it wrong. The code you have provided in the first block does not do what you say. `renderInContext` method draws the content of the viewToMagnify on the current context, not other way round.

Comment: You're right, but the code is still drawing a magnified view into loop.  I'm going to look a little more into why it works the way it does, but I don't think it will solve the issue I'm having where the view magnifies itself.

Comment: I would make a new bitmap context and render the layer onto it. Then display the result image on the magnifier view. However, make sure that the magnifier view is not in the same tree. It should be added to the superview of the view being rendered. I hope it makes sense.